# Maintain position of an image placed on top of another

Tags: html, css, layout

I have two images and one is placed on top of the other and they're supposed to look like one image. The reason I did it like this is because I want to animate image 2.

[image]

I've placed image 2 on top of image 1 and everything looks fine. The problem is, I'll be creating a component out of this and will be reusing the same css (with changes to the height and widths) and html in a few other places.

Although my styles work for one given size, as soon as it is enlarged or shrunk, image 2 changes it's placing.

This is my html,

```
<div class="container">
 <img class="image1" src="image1.png" />
 <img class="image2 animated" src="image2.png" />
</div>
```

and my css

```
.container {
 display:block;
 margin: 0 auto;
 margin-top: 30px;
 margin-bottom: 40px;
 width:43%; // width of the container will change
}
.image2 {
 margin-top: -50px; 
 margin-right: 27px; 
 float:right; 
 width: 10%;
}
```

Is there a way to place image2 and keep it in that position even though the size is changed.

If it helps clear things up more, both images together makes up the logo for my application.

Answer (score 0):

Search about the z-index property in CSS3 :

[Zindex on W3School](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

It'll do what you need

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.

Here your first image need to be in relative position, and the second in the same element in position absolute. After that you can set the bottom and right property of the second image.

```css
.container{
  width:800px;
  height:800px;
  padding:50px;
}
.img1{
  position:relative;
  width:300px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:red;
  transition: all 1s;
}

.img2{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:yellow;
  border-radius:50px;
  transition:all 1s;
  position:absolute;
  top:-90px;
  right:20px;
}
.container:hover .img1{
  width:400px;
  height:150px;
}

.container:hover .img2{
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  border-radius:100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="img1">
      <div class="img2">

      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```